# How to Expand the tappable area without increasing the button size in ios

Tags: ios, button, touch, expand, area

I am new to IOS and I want to expand the tappable area without increasing my button size.I searched through net but still i couldn't make it success.
I didn't set an image to the button and I gave it a background colour. So I can't use inset property in my XIB.What should i do?
can anybody help me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a container view contains the button, and add a tapGestureRecognizer to the container.

Comment: I tried this.it works,but the problem is i used 2 views.One for main view and the other one for button view.when i add this tapGestureRecognizer,the whole main view was tappable. But I want to make this only for button view. I have 'Ok' and 'cancel' buttons as well. So i have to specify the view.

Comment: You should add tapGestureRecognizer to button's superview,which contains the button.

Comment: How can i add this to my  button's superview,which contains the button. There is a main view as my button's superview.

Comment: So the main view contains the button, and button view contains other buttons such as 'ok' and 'cancel'? If so, make a container view as subview of main view and super view of the button. The container view should be bigger than the button, how bigger depends on how much you want to expand the tappable area.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a button larger, but make it appear smaller with `contentEdgeInsets`.